# Finding a number in a string and creating a new true/false variable

Tags: string, variables, syntax, spss

I have a two string variables (DiagnosisPrimary & DiagnosisOther) that have diagnosis coded into numerical values and delineated with '~' .
So person one was diagnosed with '20' on their first visit and then nothing on their second visit.

```
DiagnosisPrimary
20~
12~~~
20~20~
12~12~
12~~
~~~~~
12~12
```

If 20 represents having been diagnosed with depression, I want to see if there is a '20' among the string. Basically, find out who was diagnosed with depression at any of their visits. In the past I have used the formula below, but now the data is a mix of numerical and text it is no longer working.

```
COMPUTE Dx_Depression =ANY(20, DiagnosisPrimary) OR ANY(20, DiagnosisOther).
```

I want to create a new variable with a true/false response.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `CHAR.INDEX` function, which returns the position of a string in another string (or 0 if the sub string does not exist)

```
COMPUTE Dx_Depression = (CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisPrimary, '~20~') >0) or 

(CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisPrimary, '~20')=char.len(DiagnosisPrimary)-3) or 

(CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisPrimary, '20~')=1) or 

(CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisOthers, '~20~') >0) or 

(CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisOthers, '~20')=char.len(DiagnosisOthers)-3) or 

(CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisOthers, '20~')=1)
```

Comment: Just a thought - if there is a possibility for the diagnosis value to be say `200` or `120`, it will be wrongfully counted as a `20`. In order to avoid this, we need to search for '20~' at the beginning of the text or '~20~' in the middle of it. so: 
`COMPUTE Dx_Depression=CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisPrimary, '20~')=1 or CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisOther, '20~')=1 or CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisPrimary, '~20~')>1 or CHAR.INDEX(DiagnosisOther, '~20~')>1.`

Comment: @eli-k - that is a very important and correct note!

Comment: @Erin please mark the answer as accepted, if it answers your question; this way, it may help others as well